# how to override a class in a compiled web application .net dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, .net-reflector

I'm trying to change a method in a compiled C#-asp.Net web application. is it possible to somehow override a method inside a compiled dll ?!

I did reflect the dll, but it has tons of references and has been referenced tons of times, so I do not think, even if it is possible because of the hundreds of errors in Visual Studio, recompile the dll would be a good soloution.

Basically what I need to do is to change a `FormatDateTime` method inside a core dll to add support for an unsupported calendar (date format).

and of course I have access to the server of the application, and I can do what ever I want in Administrator level.

can someone guide me in a direction ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method only if it is virtual, and it doesn't matter whether you do it through reflection or statically.

It think that the best thing you can do is use a decompiler and fixe the code in MSIL. Then you can generate a new assembly from the MSIL.

For a decompiler, you can use the Telerik JustDecompile is simply awesome: http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspxI

Comment: I've already tried your solution, but the main drawback is that using this method, I can not preserve the sign of the dll and this somehow generates tons of problems, any idea on how to overcome this?!